# How can I move this header slightly below the border?

Tags: html, css, moodle

I am trying to move the title in the image off or beneath the border.

[image: title on border]

I am using a moodle theme and have tracked down the css block that is generating the border

```
.course-content .section.main {
   border:1px solid #E3E3E3;
}
```

I have tried adding padding and margins to the css rule to no avail.

```
.course-content .section.main {
   border:1px solid #E3E3E3;
   margin-top:5px;
}

.course-content .section.main {
   border:1px solid #E3E3E3;
   padding-top:5px;
}
```

I just tried border spacing, but that seems to only be applicable to tables...

```
 .course-content .section.main{
   border:1px solid #E3E3E3;
   border-spacing:5px;
  }
```

The title is surrounded by this html when viewing it in the html editor.

```
   <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
     <span style="font-size: x-large;" size="5">
       German III- HS/Part A
     </span>
   </div>
```

I do not want to have to edit the html manually, as there are hundreds of courses involved.

Comment: I'm confused by the fact that the classes you mention in your CSS aren't applied in your HTML div or span. It seems to me that the margins and paddings aren't being applied to the HTML as you expect.

Comment: You were adding padding probably to wrong selector. this HTML does not have any of these two classes. `border:1px solid #E3E3E3;` would creaate border on all four sides

Comment: moodle uses a theme where it uses the .course-content .section.main in a more global .php page.  the inline html is in a text block in a specific course.  There is border on all 4 sides of the main area, formatted by the course-content .section.main class.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're using to apply the `padding` and `margin` isn't selecting what you want it to. Neither the div nor the span have those classes, so consequently they're not getting the padding or margin that you're setting.

One option to get you your spacing would be applying `padding-top` to the span. To do this, you'll need to first find the right selector first.

As an example, the following selector should work but might not be exclusive enough (which is to say, it may apply to property to more spans on your page than the ones you want to target)

```
div > span {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```